# Sitecore App service deployment in ASE

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore8.2, sitecore-azure

I am trying to deploy Sitecore App service in my specific ASE(Ase is behind my organization firewall). I want to use two plans one for cm which will be common for my cm, cd, prc environments and another for cd. I am getting below error during my deployment

*New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 7:27:46 PM - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions '/MSDeploy' failed with message     Deployment was interrupted and the process running it was terminated unexpectedly, if an ARM template is used, the likely cause 
is a race condition. To solve the race condition, make all resources that could potentially restart the site (app settings or site config changes 
for example) have a dependency on MSDeploy resource. For more info please read the information here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808141"*

It looks like there is some dependency issue but am not able to figure out. http://entdcxsitecore.blob.core.windows.net/stackoverflowtempcontainer/AzureDeploy.json is my template. Please ignore the hard coded values. Let me know if anybody has any inputs.